# In Apache Spark SQL, How to close metastore connection from HiveContext

Tags: apache-spark, thrift, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-1.4

My project has unit tests for different HiveContext configurations (sometimes they are in one file as they are grouped by features.)

After upgrading to Spark 1.4 I encounter a lot of 'java.sql.SQLException: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database' problems, as a patch make those contexts unable to share the same metastore. Since its not clean to revert state of a singleton for every test. My only option boils down to "recycle" each context by terminating the previous Derby metastore connection. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in scala I just used FunSuite for Unit Tests together with BeforeAndAfterAll trait. Then you can just init your sparkContext in beforeAll, spawn your HiveContext from it and finish it like this:

```
  override def afterAll(): Unit = {
    if(sparkContext != null)
      sparkContext .stop()
  }
```

From what I've noticed it also closes a HiveContext attached to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Let me test it first.